Prevent Combobox SelectedValue Before Selection is Made
I am new to WPF and MVVM.  I have a Window, ViewModel, and two Models.  INotifyPropertyChanged is defined in a helper class, ObservableObject.  The _BaseViewModel inherits ObservableObject, and the ViewModel inherits _BaseViewModel.  The models contain private and public properties for the object primary number and name (example: IndustryPrimaryNum and IndustryName).
There are two comboboxes on my window, Industries and Company, bound to ObservableCollections in the ViewModel, IndustryListALL<Industry> and CompanyList<Company> respectively.  Industries is populated upon creation of the window.  When an industry is selected, the resulting companies within that industry are populated in the Company combobox.  When a company is selected, stuff should happen.
When an Industry is selected, the SelectedValue in Industries, SelectedIndustryNum in ViewModel, is assigned and that number is used to populate the CompanyList.  The problem is, while the CompanyList is populated, the SelectedCompanyNum property is assigned.  Thereby, firing the desired "stuff" too early.  How can I prevent the SelectedValue in the Company combobox from being assigned when the ItemsSource is populated?  Code is as follows:
Window XAML:
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Industries" Source="{Binding Path=IndustryListALL}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="IndustryName"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CompanyList" Source="{Binding Path=CompanyList}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="CompanyName"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>

<Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Stretch="Uniform">
    <ComboBox Name="cboIndustries" Style="{StaticResource StandardCombobox}"
            DisplayMemberPath="IndustryName"
            SelectedValuePath="IndustryPrimaryNum"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Industries}}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedIndustryNum, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    />
</Viewbox>

<Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Stretch="Uniform">
    <ComboBox Name="cboCompany" Style="{StaticResource StandardCombobox}"
            DisplayMemberPath="CompanyName"
            SelectedValuePath="CompanyPrimaryNum"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CompanyList}}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCompanyNum, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    />
</Viewbox>

ViewModel:
private ObservableCollection<Industry> _industryListALL;
private Int32 _selectedIndustryNum;
private ObservableCollection<Company> _companyList;
private Int32 _selectedCompanyNum;

public ObservableCollection<Industry> IndustryListALL
{
    get { return _industryListALL; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _industryListALL, value, () => IndustryListALL); }
}

public Int32 SelectedIndustryNum
{
    get { return _selectedIndustryNum; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _selectedIndustryNum, value, () => SelectedIndustryNum);

        if (_selectedIndustryNum == 0)
        {
            resetCompanyNamesCB();
        }
        else if (_selectedIndustryNum != 0)
        {
            resetCompanyNamesCB();
            company = new Company();
            company.fillCompaniesNamesBYIndustryPrimaryNum(SelectedIndustryNum);
            CompanyList = company.CompaniesListALL;
            SelectedCompanyNum = 0;
        }
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<Company> CompanyList
{
    get { return _companyList; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _companyList, value, () => CompanyList); }
}

public Int32 SelectedCompanyNum
{
    get { return _selectedCompanyNum; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _selectedCompanyNum, value, () => SelectedCompanyNum);

        if(_selectedCompanyNum != 0)
        {
            //*** DO STUFF ***
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}

private Industry industries { get; set; }
public Company company { get; set; }

 public WINDOWCompaniesVM() : base()
{
    industries = new Industry();
    industries.fillIndustriesALL();
}

private void resetCompanyNamesCB()
{
    if (CompanyList != null)
        CompanyList.Clear();
    SelectedCompanyNum = 0;
}


You can try setting .SelectedIndex to -1. It's a "valid" value indication "nothing selected".  Whether you then need to do something extra depends on the if, when, where, etc.

@Gerry Thank you for the response.  Unfortunately, that didn't work.  When I step through the process, I have a stop at the '{' after 'set' in 'SelectedCompanyNum'.  I notice the 'set' fires before the stop is hit when an Industry is selected.  Why would this be?

A good rule is to keep the Getter/Setter as simple as possible. I would suggest you to use xaml behavior and the routed events and not put so much logic into the setters. That way you will have more control and it would be easier to track down the issue you are encountering

"Initializing" something like "SelectedIndex" should be done in a "Loaded" event. Note that setting SelectedIndex will fire the "SelectionbChanged" event ... even when "initializing". And, rarely does one put "too much" in a "setter" without causing side effects ... better to have a "smarter" getter.
